# Xpages - Dominoview return all values if user in getRoles()

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, domino-designer-eclipse

The code below filters data in a view.

The else statement is working fine, it basically returns values for the particular user, but the if statement is where the issue is; as I want admin users to be able to view all views/records from the database.

While the if statement works, it only returns views/records for the first user, but I want it to return views for all users if the user has the Role('[Admin]').

Your help will be appreciated!

```
<xp:dominoView var="users" viewName="userView" keysExactMatch="true">
    <xp:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:var fullName = context.getUser().getFullName();
    var users:NotesView = database.getView("userView");
    var entryCol:NotesViewEntryCollection = users.getAllEntries();
    var doc:NotesDocument = users.getFirstDocument();
    var columnValues = [];
    while(doc != null){
        columnValues.push( doc.getItemValueString("CreatedBy") );
        doc = entryCol.getNextEntry();
    }
    if(context.getUser().getRoles().contains('[Admin]')){
        print(columnValues);
        return columnValues;

     }else{
     return fullName;
     }}]]></xp:this.keys>
</xp:dominoView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return an empty value `return ""` for the [Admin] people. This will not set the keys property and deliver all entries in view.

Your code would look like this then:

```xml
<xp:dominoView var="users" viewName="userView" keysExactMatch="true">
    <xp:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:
         if(context.getUser().getRoles().contains('[Admin]')){
             return "";
         } else {
             return context.getUser().getFullName();
         }
    }]]></xp:this.keys>
</xp:dominoView>
```